# Obtaining results from MongoDB with PHP (working with command line)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to obtain a simple collection doing the next:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$mongo = new Mongo();
var_dump($mongo);
$db = $mongo->testdb;
var_dump($db);

$cursor = $db->users->find();

var_dump($cursor);
?>
```

And I get the next output:

```
object(Mongo)#1 (4) {
  ["connected"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["status"]=>
  NULL
  ["server":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["persistent":protected]=>
  NULL
}
object(MongoDB)#2 (2) {
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wtimeout"]=>
  int(10000)
}
object(MongoCursor)#4 (0) {
}
```

IF in the command line I do this:

```
use testdb;
db.users.find();
```

I obtain:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fca596803fa4b53000000"), "username" : "test4", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test4@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fca6e6803fa4a53000000"), "username" : "test4", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test4@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fca726803fa4a53000001"), "username" : "test4", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test4@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fca736803fa4a53000002"), "username" : "test4", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test4@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fcae26803fa4c53000000"), "username" : "test4", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test4@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7fcb076803fa4953000000"), "username" : "test1", "password" : "md5pass", "email" : "test1@email.tld", "group" : 1, "profile_fields" : "a:0:{}" }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `foreach` on the Cursor in your first example.

The reason being you do not see anything in the `var_dump` is that it is a `resource`. Resources are pointers, they do not hold real data by themselves.